# Connecting a JVC home theatre speaker to a computer

Tags: audio, speakers

I am using a JVC sound system with my TV, and I recently bought a new center speaker to the JVC. I love using spare gadgets to create something, so I decided to use the replaced center speaker with my self-built desktop computer. Unlike the JVC, my computer has minijack stereo audio outputs instead of speaker terminals. The speaker has a connector identical to the connectors on the back of the JVC. Can I just Y-split the audio signal from the computer minijack and connect one of the signals to the speaker (for example LEFT to red and GND to black)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split a normal TRS audio cable into 3 wires (L, R, GND) or a TS audio cable into 2 wires (L, GND). GND connects to the black terminal, while L or R connects to red.

[Stereo minijack pinout](http://pinouts.ru/Home/Tele35s_pinout.shtml):

[image: L - tip, R - ring, GND - sleeve]